# How to give condition to aliased column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, alias

How can I give a condition to a column with an alias in this query?

My query:

```
select
cnt.id as content_id,
cnt.title as content_title,
cnt.introtext,
cnt.fulltext,
cnt.ordering,
cnt.images,
cnt.alias,
cnt.state,
cnt.catid,
f.item_id,
cat.id as cat_id,
cat.title as cat_title,
max(case when f.field_id = 1 then f.value end) as inslider,
max(case when f.field_id = 2 then f.value end) as sliderquote
from snm_fields_values f
join snm_content cnt
on cnt.id = f.item_id
join snm_categories cat
on cnt.catid = cat.id
where cnt.state = 1
and f.value = 'ja'
group by f.item_id
order by f.item_id, inslider
```

This returns the following:

[image]

`sliderquote` is NULL because it checks if f.value equals 'ja' which it never does. If I remove the condition I get the correct data that is in that row, but I need the condition.

How can I still have it and only apply it to `sliderquote`?

`AND sliderquote = 'ja'` doesn't work because SQL doesn't read aliases like that I learned.

What can I do?

Comment: This looks like MySQL code, invalid MySQL code to be exact.  You are grouping by `item_id` but then selecting a ton of other columns.

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/) can help you

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read and understand (and write.)

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. (And I can't read that image's tiny image.)

Comment: Hint: HAVING clause. Or derived table (subquery.)

Comment: @jarlh Click on it, I can't format it nicely on SO, I've tried a lot of times. I know it is better practice to add text, but for tables it is too much of a hassle.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using phpMyAdmin

Comment: That's not a DBMS, that's a database frontend. But as it only supports MySQL it's safe to assume that you are using MySQL (which the invalid `GROUP BY` was indicating anyway)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Why is it invalid? When I remove it I get only one result but there are more results than 1.

Comment: Every self-respecting DBMS will reject that `group by` because you have non-aggregated column in the SELECT list that are not included in the `group by` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might need a nested request, like so :

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT cnt.id    AS content_id,
               cnt.title AS content_title,
               cnt.introtext,
               cnt.fulltext,
               cnt.ordering,
               cnt.images,
               cnt.alias,
               cnt.state,
               cnt.catid,
               f.item_id,
               cat.id    AS cat_id,
               cat.title AS cat_title,
               Max(CASE
                     WHEN f.field_id = 1 THEN f.value
                   END)  AS inslider,
               Max(CASE
                     WHEN f.field_id = 2 THEN f.value
                   END)  AS sliderquote
        FROM   snm_fields_values f
               JOIN snm_content cnt
                 ON cnt.id = f.item_id
               JOIN snm_categories cat
                 ON cnt.catid = cat.id
        WHERE  cnt.state = 1
        GROUP  BY f.item_id
        ORDER  BY f.item_id,
                  inslider)T
WHERE  T.sliderquote = 'ja'
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer returned empty because `T.sliderquote` needs to be `T.inslider`. After I changed that it works perfect. I didn't know you could nest queries with an alias like that. Learned something new, thanks.